# forloop iteration over arrays in python (append the value)

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I would like to create a function that iterates over two arrays `X` and `Y` and return another array `Z`.
The basic is to initialize the first item of the array `Z` with a constant (c) and iterate for the rest of the items:
the function would return this :

```
Z[0]= c
Z[1] = Z[0] + (X[0] - Y[0]) 
Z[2] = Z[1] + (X[1] - Y[1]) 
Z[n] = Z[n-1] + (X[n-1] - Y[n-1])
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the `Z[2]` be `Z[2] = Z[1] + (X[1] - Y[1])`? (not `Y[10]`)

Comment: You should add some code showing what you tried this far. Don't expect to get solutions for your exercises without proving that you at least tried to solve the exercises.